# Conditional UPDATE on a sqlite3 table with different WHERE parameters

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm a white belt on SQL-fu and I need some help. Is it possible to do a conditional UPDATE on a sqlite3 table with different WHERE arguments? I'm trying to make triggers, but I fail to make it work properly.
Something in the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS table_reorder BEFORE UPDATE ON table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
*IF* new.index > index *THEN* index + 1 WHERE index > new.index END
*ELSE IF* new.index < index *THEN* index - 1 WHERE index < new.index END
END;
```

Or if you have a better idea to make this work, please let me know. I've tried the solution proposed on [SQLite: UPDATE column of multiple rows with sequential value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537046/sqlite-update-column-of-multiple-rows-with-sequential-value), but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Could you please describe in English what you are trying to do?  I can't tell.  Also, this doesn't strike me as an appropriate use of a trigger.  I think perhaps you should post the other code that you tried that didn't work.  It might be a better starting point.

Comment: I want to have a col with a unique integer that is used for positioning items in order of importance. I don't know how to make this entire col self-update when I update the importance of one entry. If i update and entry, the entire col must refresh/update accordingly. Does it make sense?

Comment: I doubt that such a trigger makes sense for an order column. What if you just want to exchange the order of two entries? In theory, no other entries need to be changed.

Comment: @CL in such case, i'd set only one, since the other one would be automatically corrected. of course, this is a solution for this program only, not a general usage. for instance, i figured ordering works if i increase the values of all entries (greater ir equal) after the new set position - position values wont be 1,2,3,4 (eventually it will be more like 1,5,14,29) but still works as order of importance. but it doesnt look nicely done to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`WHEN` condition](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) on triggers.
And if you want an update, you have to actually execute it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_reorder_larger
BEFORE UPDATE OF index ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.index > OLD.index
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET index = index + 1 WHERE index > NEW.index;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER table_reorder_smaller
BEFORE UPDATE OF index ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.index < OLD.index
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET index = index - 1 WHERE index < NEW.index;
END;
```

However, this will run the same trigger recursively, so you better disable [recursive triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers).

Comment: would running this trigger recursively be only a matter of optimization/bad practice or is there any incurring problem? thanks for that though.

Comment: The trigger would be run *again* for the `index` values one step further.